# Setting WindowButtonCommands styles in Mahapps.Metro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, titlebar, mahapps.metro

I want to change the style of the Min, Max and Close buttons for my WPF application.

I'm using [Mahapps.Metro](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro) and I have successfully managed to achieve the result I want, but only with the obsolete `WindowMinButtonStyle`, `WindowMaxButtonStyle` and `WindowCloseButtonStyle` properties in the `MetroWindow` class. The obsolete message on for example the `WindowMinButtonStyle` property reads:

> This property will be deleted in the next release. You should use LightMinButtonStyle or DarkMinButtonStyle in WindowButtonCommands to override the style.

The problem is that I can't figure out how specifically to do that. The `MetroWindow` class has a field called `WindowButtonCommands`, but it is `internal`, so that seems to be the wrong tree to bark up. I'm fairly new to WPF and there is no info on how to do this in the guides on their website, so I'm pretty lost. I'm hoping someone can provide me with a short code example to point me in the right direction.

**EDIT** - Here is XAML that produces the warning:

```
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
        WindowMinButtonStyle="{DynamicResource DarkWindowButtonStyle}"
        WindowMaxButtonStyle="{DynamicResource DarkWindowButtonStyle}"
        WindowCloseButtonStyle="{DynamicResource DarkWindowCloseButtonStyle}">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</controls:MetroWindow>
```

I should also mention I'm using the new v1.2.0 of Mahapps.Metro, but I had the same issue with the previous version.
Mahapps.Metro source code that has the `Obsolete` attributes: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/MahApps.Metro/Controls/MetroWindow.cs#L88-L93

Comment: I changed `WindowMinButtonStyle` and did not get any warnings. Show your XAML.

Comment: @jstreet Thank you for looking into this, I edited my question with XAML and more info.

Comment: I'm using version 1.1.3.0..... Please show your `DarkWindowButtonStyle` as well.

Comment: @jstreet I don't see how the style is relevant, a completely blank style produces the same warning. The issue is that the properties are marked as obsolete, clearly there is supposed to be a different way of assigning the style.

Comment: Try using either `LightMinButtonStyle` or `DarkMinButtonStyle`, depending on the `Accent` you're using. These aren't available in version 1.1.3.0 but are supposed to replace `WindowMinButtonStyle` at some point in time, possibly in version 1.2.0

Comment: @jstreet That does not work because those properties are in the `WindowButtonCommans` class, not in the `MetroWindow` class. Each `MetroWindow` has an instance of the `WindowButtonCommands` class as an internal field. When using for example the `WindowMinButtonStyle` property, one is setting the style of that internal instance. The more I look into this, the more I'm thinking that this whole situation is an oversight on their part. I think I may post in the Issues section of their Github. Thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

based on [crumbl3d](https://github.com/crumbl3d) [changes](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/pull/2152), a short how to...

There are now two styles (Light, Dark) which will be used based on `OverrideDefaultWindowCommandsBrush` property (available at `MetroWindow`) and it's lightness (default is the Light style).

So, put these at your `App.xaml` (or something else)

```
<Style x:Key="CustomLightMetroWindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource LightMetroWindowButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Chocolate" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="CustomDarkMetroWindowButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource DarkMetroWindowButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Crimson" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:WindowButtonCommands}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:WindowButtonCommands}}">
    <Setter Property="LightMinButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomLightMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="LightMaxButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomLightMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="LightCloseButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomLightMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="DarkMinButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomDarkMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="DarkMaxButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomDarkMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="DarkCloseButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomDarkMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
</Style>
```

**Edit**

If you only want to use this at one window then you can create a style with a key and use it at this window like this:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.WindowButtonCommands>
    <controls:WindowButtonCommands Style="{DynamicResource CustomWindowButtonCommandsStyleLocatedtInAppXaml}" />
</controls:MetroWindow.WindowButtonCommands>
```

The style located in App.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="CustomWindowButtonCommandsStyleLocatedtInAppXaml" TargetType="{x:Type controls:WindowButtonCommands}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:WindowButtonCommands}}">
    <Setter Property="LightMinButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomLightMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="LightMaxButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomLightMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="LightCloseButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomLightMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="DarkMinButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomDarkMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="DarkMaxButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomDarkMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="DarkCloseButtonStyle" Value="{StaticResource CustomDarkMetroWindowButtonStyle}" />
</Style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if I want to change a close button for one window only and not all windows?

Comment: @xmedeko You can create another WindowButtonCommands style and give it a key. Then you can use this at this window...

Comment: As of now the `Sytle` base is out dated. New: `BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button.MetroWindow.Dark}">`. Had to do some digging.