# change the icon of the close button in MahApps MetroWindow

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, titlebar, mahapps.metro

I'm making a **WPF** app using **MahApps** . it can change the titlebar icons to minimize , maximize and close the window ? I searched online but found little about it , but before looking for another solution I wanted to share with you this question .

i have try custom with this, but not change the icon image

```
<Style x:Key="MetroWindowCloseButtonStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroWindowButtonStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" Background="#000">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="grid" Property="Background" Value="#E04343" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter" Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="grid" Property="Background" Value="#993D3D" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

it possibile change icon ? thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you comment-out the ContentPresenter, does the icon disappear?
If it does, that would suggest you can change the icon simply by putting your own icon inside the button's content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting WindowButtonCommands styles in Mahapps.Metro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563155/setting-windowbuttoncommands-styles-in-mahapps-metro)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing Mahapps.MetroWindow Close Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749094/customizing-mahapps-metrowindow-close-button)

Answer (score 1):

The same question [was asked at Github](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2290) a couple of days ago. [punker76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920384/punker76) described [the solution in a comment](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/2290#issuecomment-168673660).